# Counting classes on another page and displaying them

Tags: javascript, jquery

To save me a lot of work editing a number in when adding a document to a site I decided to use javascript to count the number of elements with a class `doc` .

I am two main problems:

- There is trouble displaying the variable. I initially thought this was because I hadn't added `function`, however when I tried adding this the variable was still not displayed.
- The elements with the class I want to count are on another page and I have no idea how to link to it. For this I have tried `var x = $('URL: /*pageURL*/ .doc').length;` which hasn't worked.

Essentially I want the total elements with said class name and this to be displayed in a span element.

Currently I have something similar to what's displayed below:

```
 <script>
 var Items = $('.doc').length;
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=Items;
 </script>
 <span id="display"></span>
```

Found an example of something similar [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aStatistics) where the total numbers of articles are displayed.

**Edit:**

@ian
This code will be added to the homepage, domain.net/home.html. I want to link to the page containing this documents, domain.net/documents.html. I've seen this done somewhere before and if I remember correctly they used `url:domainname.com/count` somewhere in their code. Hope this helps.

Comment: `.InnerHTML` should be `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Are you trying to identify elements on a different DOM?  I don't think that can be done.  Unless you want to use a very complex AJAX solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "on another page"? Where is the page? And how is it being accessed?

Comment: @am-not-i-am my bad, missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to wait until the `document` is ready before manipulating `DOM` elements, unless your code is placed **after** the definition of the elements you manipulate, wich is not the case in your example. You can pass a `function` to the `$` and it will run it only when the document is ready.

```
$(function () {
    //html() allows to set the innerHTML property of an element
    $('#display').html($('.doc').length);
});
```

Now, if your elements belongs to another `document`, that obviously won't work. However, if you have used `window.open` to open another window wich holds the document that contains the `.doc` elements, you could put the above script in that page, and rely on `window.opener` to reference the `span` in the parent's window.

```
$('#display', opener.document.body).html($('.doc').length);
```

Another alternative would be to use **ajax** to access the content of the other page. Here, `data` will contain the HTML of the `your_other_page.html` document, wich you can then manipulate like a DOM structure using jQuery.

```
$.get('your_other_page.html', function(data) {
    $('#display').html($('.doc', data).length);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jQuery call to retrieve the url "./" (this page) and parse the resulting data for all elements with class "lsep" "$('.lsep', data)".  You should get back a number greater than 5 or so if you run this from within your debug console of your browser.

```
$.get("./", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    console.log("Instances of class: " + $('.lsep', data).length)
});
```

One important thing to remember is that you will run into issues if the URL your are trying to call is not in the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Here's an updated snippet of code to do what you're describing:

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
      //var url = "/document.html" //this is what you'd have for url
      //var container = $("#display"); //this is what you'd have for container
      //var className = '.data'; //this is what you'd have for className

        var url = "./"; //the document you want to parse
        var container = $("#question-header"); //the container to update
        var className = '.lsep'; //the class to search for

        $.get(url, function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $(container).html($(className, data).length);
        });
    }
);
```

If you run the above code from your browser's debug console it will replace the question header text of "**Counting classes on another page and displaying them**" with the count of instances the class name ".lsep" is used.

Comment: unfortunately neither of these suggestions appear to work. it's probably my own fault as it is likely i've implemented it incorrectly.